# How to terminate SSL on load balancer (Apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I'd like to know how to terminate SSL on the load balancer using Apache. I would then like to know how to create a secondary SSL connection to the backend web cluster?

Here's what I have, but I'm getting redirect loops.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mywebsite.com
  Redirect 301 / https://mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName mywebsite.com

   <Proxy balancer://web_farm>
      BalancerMember http://IP_ADDR_1
      BalancerMember http://IP_ADDR_2
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / balancer://web_farm:443/
   ProxyPassReverse / balancer://web_farm:443/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Add your certs to the SSL virtualhost as if you were hosting the site on the virtual host, and change the BslancerMembesr from http to https. You probably need to enable SSLProxyEngine as well.

Comment: awesome, i'll give this a shot